# post_menu segmentation fault (core dump)

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, ncurses, coredump

I just started to program with Ncurses, but, when i launch this program, I get "Segmentation fault (core dump)".
It occurs when I call function post_menu(...).

```
char *mainMenu_choices[] = {
           "Say Hello!",
           "Close", 
           };
ITEM **mainMenu_items = (ITEM **)NULL;
MENU *mainMenu = (MENU *)NULL;
int mainMenu_choices_COUNT, i = 0;
int mainMenu_status = TRUE;
ITEM *mainMenu_selectedItem = (ITEM *)NULL;

int draw_mainMenu()
{
     mainMenu_status = TRUE;
     mainMenu_choices_COUNT = ARRAY_SIZE(mainMenu_choices);
     mainMenu_items = (ITEM **)calloc(mainMenu_choices_COUNT + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));
     for(i = 0; i < mainMenu_choices_COUNT; i = i + 1)
     {                              
          mainMenu_items = new_item(mainMenu_choices[i], mainMenu_choices[i]);
     }
     mainMenu_items[mainMenu_choices_COUNT] = (ITEM *)NULL;     
     mainMenu = new_menu((ITEM **)mainMenu_items);
     post_menu(mainMenu);
     refresh();
     return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.
PS: Sorry if I didn't put comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not filling `mainMenu_items` correctly inside the loop.

You are doing

```
mainMenu_items = ...
```

but you probably meant

```
mainMenu_items[i] = ...
```